# Turn curve into a path?

Tags: modeling

I have a curve wrapping around my model and a few orbs I wish to animate around it. How do I convert the curve into a path so I can easily animate it?

[image]

I figured out how to move it along but now the ball won't stay inside of the curve and it just flys around it and it's not sold inside the curve?

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between a curve and a path?

Comment: make sure that the origin of the sphere is the same as the curve's

Comment: A path is something an object follows

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/how-can-i-make-an-object-follow-a-path-exactly/42074#42074

Comment: There is no such thing in Blender, there are no "path" objects, only curves that may be used as a path. If your object is offset in relation to the curve check the object's origin as cegaton mentioned

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I don't think Muly is suggesting there is a "path" object, I think he is just trying to say he wants his object to follow the curve.

Answer (score 2):

In blender, I know of no difference between curves and paths.
I believe that a few things could be happening.

1) Make sure that the orbs are children of the curve

2) See that Data > Path Animation is checked

3) You might also want the Frames value under Data > Path Animation to be equal to the length of your animation.

If all of these are done, and it is still not working, please upload your .blend file.

Comment: Thanks Billy, I'm currently trying the path over the curve.  I will also try your suggestions as well.