# Why won't my object follow the path I give it?

Tags: bezier-curves

When I apply the curve modifier to my fence that I have it put it somewhere totally random on the screen and doesn't follow the curve at all?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/how-can-i-make-an-object-follow-a-path-exactly/42074#42074

Answer (score 1):

ensure both the outline and the fence element share their origin.

eg, like this, before enabling modifiers:

[image]

then, if you enable them:

[image]